# OrmLite delete failed

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am performing a simple delete of a ormlite object. The code is below. But no matter what, the object never get deleted.

```
Dao<Subscription, Object> dao = helper.getSubscriptionDataDao();

dao = helper.getSubscriptionDataDao();
QueryBuilder<Subscription, Object> query = dao.queryBuilder();
query.where().eq("key", subKey);
Subscription sub = dao.queryForFirst(query.prepare());
int r = dao.delete(sub); // r is 1
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Any chance you are in a transactions that gets rolled back Seymore?  Any chance there are multiple subscriptions with the same key?  If you do a queryForFirst immediately after the delete, do you get the same subscription back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solve the problem: Make sure the object have primary key. Setting the field as ID does not mean the ID will be auto generated. Without the ID, delete will fail.

Comment: So you got a 1 back from dao.delete() but the id was not set?  What did you delete?

Comment: Yes this is the case. The object DatabaseField is set to ID but not auto-generate ID so somehow when I do a print of the ID, it's null. Once I set the object ID field to auto-generate=true, the delete will be successful. Sounds like a bug. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense to me now.  You were deleting the first row in the database that had a null key.  There must be more than one.  Let me know if there is missing documentation about `id = true` versus `generatedId = true`.

Comment: I have a similar issue - I want to delete all Pictures with a given column value. The number of expected rows to delete should be >=1 in my case but its always 1. Before the delete I checked how many entries should be deleted (using a select) and no matter the number, the result from delete is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

You must create `DeleteBuilder` for `Delete.QueryBuilder` just for get Query for Select .

```
public int deleteByObjectId(int objectId) throws SQLException, java.sql.SQLException 
{
    DAL<T> helper= new DAL<T>(_context, type);
    RuntimeExceptionDao<T, Integer> dao =helper.getSimpleDataDao2();
    DeleteBuilder<T, Integer> delBuilder =dao.deleteBuilder();    
    delBuilder.where().eq("ObjId", objectId);
    PreparedDelete<T> prepareQery=delBuilder.prepare();
    int i=dao.delete(prepareQery);
    return i;
 }
```